# What is the derivative of the function and the slope at the given two points?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I was asked to find the derivative of the function $f(x)=x^3+2x$ using the limit definition of derivatives and find the slope at $(1,3)$ and $(-1,-3)$.

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(x+h)^3+2(x+h)-x^3-2x}{h}$$
$$\implies \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{x^3+3x^2h+3xh^2+h^3+2x+2h-x^3-2x}{h}$$
$$\implies \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h(3x^2+3xh+h^2+2)}{h}$$
$$\implies \lim_{h\to 0}3x^2+3xh+h^2+2$$
$$\implies \lim_{h\to 0}3x^2+2$$
$$\implies \boxed{f'(x)=3x^2+2}$$

Above is my answer for the derivative of the function but I have no idea how to find the slope at the points $(1,3)$ and $(-1,-3)$.

Comment: You just evaluate at $f'(x=1)$ and $f'(x=-1)$. the $3$ and $-3$ signify the image of $x=1$ and $x= -1$ meaning that $f(1) = 3, f(-1) = -3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the slope at points $(1,3)$ and $(-1,-3)$ you simply have to evaluate $f'(1)$ and $f'(-1)$.
The function $f'(x)$ will give you the slope of the curve for every value of $x$. Hence to evaluate the slope at $x=1$ or $x=-1$ you simply plug in those values into $f'(x)$.

Comment: so it means the slopes are $f'(1)=5$ and $f'(-1)=-1$?

Comment: @harpey1111 Nope. $f'(-1)$ is also $5$